Create a dynamic dictionary in apps script google sheet
I have a column with data in google sheets like this:
col_name
A
A
A
B
B
C

I want to store this data in a dictionary where column value is a key and number of occurrences is a value:
dict = {A:3, B:2, C:1}

I tried to iterate through a list of values:
col_values = mySheet.getRange(2, col, last_row-1, 1).getValues();

With a function:
function count_occurances_in_col(col_values){
  let occurances_dict = new Map();
  for(var i=0;i<=col_values.length;i++){
    if(occurances_dict.has(col_values[i][0])){
      let value = occurances_dict.get(col_values[i][0]);
      occurances_dict.set(col_values[i][0], value+1);
    } else {
      occurances_dict.set(col_values[i][0], 1);
    }
  }
  return occurances_dict;
};

But the function returns undefined instead of a dictionary (perhaps) because keys are set dynamically (if I understood correctly the forums - I don't know JS well, only python).
Can I obtain such a dict with some function or any other way?
Notice that getValues() method returns col_values in a form:
[[A], [A], [A], [B], [B], [C]]


The simplest way to get a dictionary is to use a plain vanilla Object, like this:
function countOccurances(keys = [], dict = {}) {
  keys.forEach(v => dict[v] = 1 + (Number(dict[v]) || 0));
  return dict;
}

The function above can be called with just an array of keys, and it will return a new Object that looks like { A: 3, B: 2, C: 1 }.
The function can also be called with an existing dictionary, in which case the function will modify that dictionary, incrementing counts and  adding keys as required.
To test the function, try something like this:
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const keys = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const result = countOccurances(keys);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

The test() function will log and return the result in the format { A: 3, B: 2, C: 1 }.


Note: The answers provided by the other community members are all working. This is to provide additional information on where the code can be run because it was stated that I don't know JS well, only python.

If the script is intended to be a Custom Functions in Google Sheets, you can modify the code to:
function count_occurances_in_col(col_values) {
  let occurances_dict = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < col_values.length; i++) {
    let value = col_values[i];
    if (occurances_dict[value]) {
      occurances_dict[value] += 1;
    } else {
      occurances_dict[value] = 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(occurances_dict);
  return JSON.stringify(occurances_dict);
}


This uses JSON.stringify() so that the object will show up in the spreadsheet, and it can be used like this:

=count_occurances_in_col(range)

OUTPUT


The Executions tab of Google Apps Script would also show something like this if you choose to keep console.log(occurances_dict);.


If the script is intended to be used in Google Apps Script, you can modify the code to:
function count_occurances_in_col() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col_values = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  let occurances_dict = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < col_values.length; i++) {
    let value = col_values[i];
    if (occurances_dict[value]) {
      occurances_dict[value] += 1;
    } else {
      occurances_dict[value] = 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(occurances_dict);
}

OUTPUT

This is another way that you can write the script:
function count_occurances_in_col() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col_values = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  let occurances_dict = {};
  col_values.forEach(value => {
    var rx = new RegExp(value, 'g');
    var match = col_values.join().match(rx);
    occurances_dict[value] = match.length;
  });
  console.log(occurances_dict);
}

OUTPUT


This should work
const col = 1;
const last_row = mySheet.getLastRow();
col_values = mySheet.getRange(2, col, last_row - 1, 1).getValues();



function count_occurances_in_col(col_values) {
    let occurances_dict = {};
    for (var i = 0; i <= col_values.length -1 ; i++) { 
        if (occurances_dict[col_values[i][0]] != undefined) {
            occurances_dict[col_values[i][0]] += 1;
        } else {
            occurances_dict[col_values[i][0]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return occurances_dict;
};


Here is an example using Set to get the unique values of col_values and then count the number of occurances.
Code.gs
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test");
    let col = 1;
    let last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
    let col_values = sheet.getRange(2,col,last_row-1,1).getValues().flat();
    let keys = [...new Set(col_values)];
    let dict = {};
    keys.forEach( key => dict[key] = 0 );
    col_values.forEach( key => dict[key[0]]++ );
    console.log(dict);    
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}

Execution log
7:02:47 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:02:48 AM  Info    { A: 3, B: 2, C: 1 }
7:02:48 AM  Notice  Execution completed


Try this:
 function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const obj = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().reduce((a,v,i) => {
    if(!a.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
      a[v]=1;     
    } else {
      a[v] += 1;
    }
    return a;
  },{});
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
 }

Execution log
11:24:06 AM Notice  Execution started
11:24:03 AM Info    {"A":3,"B":2,"C":1}
11:24:08 AM Notice  Execution completed

